# How the get one of the values in the output array from previous in-line code action?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, inline-code

I use in-line code action to get the user's info and return an array, now i want to get the email address and the name to send an email.

I tried the expression: Outputs('action name')[1], but it shows that the template is invalid.

Thank You!

How can i get the values(name and email address) in this array?

Comment: Show us some screenshots then. Too hard to help without it. The screenshots should include the output from the inline code action.

Answer (score 0):

to get a specific field of one array element you can use this:

variables('MyArray')?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veEFx.png)?['Email_Address']

Where MyArray is the name of the Array Variable:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veEFx.png) is the array element position
and [Email_Address] the element field

Considering the Array:

```
[
  {
    "Email_Address": "value1@test.com",
    "Email_Address2": "value2@test.com",
    "Email_Address3": "value3@test.com"
  },
  {
    "Email_Address": "value4@test.com",
    "Email_Address2": "value5@test.com",
    "Email_Address3": "value6@test.com"
  }
]
```

variables('MyArray')?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veEFx.png)?['Email_Address'] will result in:

[image]

But are you sure the value you need will always be in the same place? is the array always the same amount of items?

maybe you may find better alternatives with an Array filter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#filter-array-action?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5005174

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @BrunoLucasAzure, And assuming your output from Inline code will be something like:

```
[{
"Email_Address":"rithwik@gmail.com",
"name":"Rithwik"
}]
```

Now firstly you need to set the output to a variable or initialize it to a variable then you can use below steps:

```
variables('emo')[0]['name']
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

If you want email address then use:

```
variables('emo')[0]['Email_Address']
```

[image]

Output:

[image]